# Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD) ARM Feed API Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, wvd

When WVD was launched you could get an user impersonation token.
With this token you could get feed information from:

`https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/api/feeddiscovery/webfeeddiscovery.aspx`

With the new fall 2019 update the url for the webclient changed from:

`https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/webclient`

to:

`https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient`

The token I used for the "old" webclient isn't working for the new one.
The new feed discovery url returns 401 Unauthorized:

`https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/api/arm/feeddiscovery`

I used Fiddler to view the token I would get when I signed into the arm webclient.
It no longer used an impersonation token, but a undocumented "WindowsVirtualDesktop.AccessAll" scope. Does anyone know how to get a token for the new arm endpoint to get the user feed?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is expected - you need a token for the new API endpoint, with the new AppId (check the reply of the 401 - you will see the WWW-Authenticate header what is the appId).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are using an app registration or a user, I believe with the new arm endpoints you need to have a role in the subscription rbac.

You can create a custom role in the Azure AD subscription level, please take a look at the Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization category of role permissions, then assign the service / user that role

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/getting-started-windows-virtual-desktop-arm-based-azure-portal/ba-p/1374466

Comment: Doesn't say anything about the feed api :(